# Is it possible to block users?

Tags: support

I find some users unhelpful and abrasive as if they just seem to enjoy arguing for its own sake without building any collaborative insight. Is it possible to hide all of their contributions when I browse the site?

Answer (score 1):

**Is it possible to block users?**

Here's one option: [Ignore Users Script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3360/906208)